# Linux find and grep command together

Tags: bash, grep, find

I am trying to find a command or create a Linux script that can do this two commands and list the output

```
find . -name '*bills*' -print
```

this prints all the files

```
./may/batch_bills_123.log
./april/batch_bills_456.log
..
```

from this result I want to do a grep for a word I do this manually right now

```
grep 'put' ./may/batch_bill_123.log
```

and get

```
sftp > put oldnet_1234.lst
```

I would hope to get the file name and its match.

```
./may/batch_bills_123.log   sftp > put oldnet_1234.lst
..
..
and so on...
```

do you have any ideas?

Comment: `find . -name '*bills*' -exec grep put {} \;`

Comment: Or even `find . -name "*bills*" -print0 | xargs -0 grep put`...

Answer (score 147, accepted):

You are looking for `-H` option in gnu grep.

```
find . -name '*bills*' -exec grep -H "put" {} \;
```

#### Here is the explanation

```
    -H, --with-filename
      Print the filename for each match.
```

Comment: The nice thing about using `grep` with `find` is you can set `-maxdepth` on `find`, which you can't when just using `grep -R`.

Answer (score 68):

Now that the question is clearer, you can just do this in one [grep](/questions/tagged/grep)

```
grep -R --include "*bills*" "put" .
```

With relevant flags

```
   -R, -r, --recursive
          Read  all  files  under  each  directory,  recursively;  this is
          equivalent to the -d recurse option.
   --include=GLOB
          Search only files whose base name matches GLOB  (using  wildcard
          matching as described under --exclude).
```

Comment: Good way to use `--include`, but when I run the command with no match in `--include` option, it prompts `Too many levels of symbolic links`, switch to `-R` and `-r`, get same error.

Comment: @BMW Interesting, can't replicate, but sounds like it's reaching some symlink threshold that it's not happy about. A bit surprised that would be default behavior for a recursive option.

Answer (score 10):

Or maybe even easier

```
grep -R put **/*bills*
```

The `**` glob syntax means "any depth of directories".  It will work in Zsh, and I think recent versions of Bash too.

Comment: Depending on how many matched files you have, you might get `zsh: argument list too long: grep`

Comment: In bash you need to enable it first.
```shopt -s globstar```

Answer (score 5):

```
grep -l "$SEARCH_TEXT" $(find "$SEARCH_DIR" -name "$TARGET_FILE_NAME")
```