# How to find filename in file content with bash script?

Tags: linux, bash

I wrote this command in my shell but it's not doing what I wanted and I can't figure out what I did wrong. I want to get files from current directories which include their names in their content.

```
find -type f -exec grep -il {} +
```

I understand `find -type f` gives me standard files from the directory and `-exec` executes following `grep` command with pattern - which is filename - on given file ('+'). Am I right? Because it seems like I don't understand something since it's not finding my file specially created for this purpose.

Comment: `Am I right?` Quite, the pattern is not filename, but path to the file. `my file` what is the filename and content of your file exactly?

Comment: The file name is "plik.txt." and its content includes a bunch of lines including ones saying "plik.txt" and "./plik.txt".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> on given file ('+')

`+` executes the command on *all* found files. The `{}` is replaced by *the list* of files in current directory.

Debug with `-exec echo grep -il {} +`.

You want:

```
-exec grep -Fil {} {} ';'
```

To search the filename `{}` as a pattern in the file named `{}`. The `';'` terminates the command.

I also added `-F` to interpret pattern literally.

Comment: Wow, thanks! That does the trick. Can you also tell me what difference make single quotes around the semicolon? I'm guessing this was actually my problem because I was trying this combination exactly (I mean "{} {}") but I was getting an error of missing argument to "-exec".

Comment: `what difference make single quotes around the semicolon?` command are delimitered by `;` or by newline, like `echo 123 ; echo 234 ; echo 345`. The `;` has to be passed literally to the `find` command, so it's a string tha contains `;` character, not a special shell delimiter, so `';'` or `\;` or `";"`. I.e. compare `echo 123 ';' echo 234` to `echo 123 ; echo 234`.

Comment: So it has to be literal so `grep` doesn't treat it as an argument?

Comment: `grep` parses REGEX, if it's not literal, for example `.` `[` `(` `*` `+` characters have special meaning. `.` matches any character, see `man 7 regex`. Regex `./plik.txt` matches `a/plikbtxt` for example.

Answer (score 0):

File in current directory `test.txt`

Content of file includes "test"

`find . -name 'test.txt' -exec grep -i 'test' {} \;`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21763904/linux-find-and-grep-command-together